# Identify orthogonal and non-orthogonal Polygon and fracture them

Tags: python-2.7, boost, boost-geometry

we are using boost polygon library to perform polygon operation. In latest scenario I need to determine following point.

1. **Identify if Polygon is orthogonal or non orthogonal and will be receiving following coordinates as a Input**.

   Input look like python list as we have some interface

   > data =  [(100, 100), (100, 200), (300, 200), (600, 400), (1150, 400),
   >   (1150,300), (600,300), (300,100)](These data point create following
   >   NON orthogonal Polygon)
   >    [image]
   >
   > data =  [(550 , 221), (800 , 221), (800 , 269), (1090 , 269), (1090 ,
   >   173), (1520 , 173), (1520 , 269), (1810 , 269), (1810 , 173), (2420 ,
   >   173), (2420 , 221), (2708 , 221), (2708 , 317), (550 , 317) ]
   >
   > These data point create orthogonal Polygon
   >   [image]
2. What should be behavior if we are doing fracture in horizontal or vertical
   direction of Non Orthogonal polygon and Orthogonal Polygon as we need to handle both polygon
3. Can we get Vertical and horizontal rectangle from Non orthogonal.

Could not add Image as I do not have 10 reputation.

Comment: Can you link to an image? Because the prose is not exactly helpful. Perhaps seeing a picture will provide an "Ahah". But there's not a lot we can do right now.

Comment: I added the images for the sample polys. Good luck with thinking of the algorithm. If you can be sure that there's no rotation involved (i.e. all edges are aligned to the axes of the coordinate system) then it should be very simple to traverse the list and check for "overlapping" x/y on all adjacent points).